# What type of design patterns do you use regularly?

Tags: design-patterns

What type of design patterns do you use regularly? I'm trying to get an idea of how formal people code.

Factory, builder, strategy patterns, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: This will probably get voted as off-topic. I'm not sure if Programmers stack exchange would be better or not (it may be off-topic there as well).

Comment: why would it be off topic...i'm asking about design patterns.

Comment: Because it doesn't have a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use most of the GoF patterns on a regular basis.  I've had to implement all of them at least once in the course of my career.

Languages and libraries written since GoF published incorporate several patterns into their APIs.  Java has Observable, Iterators and Proxies for example.

Almost all of my code makes some use of Factories, Builders, Strategies, Adapters, Decorators etc.  Anything complex has to in order to keep it easily maintainable and extendable.

I would recommend reading [Holub on Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430253614) where the author writes 2 programs that use all the GoF patterns together.  It really shows how patterns work together.

Comment: All 23 patterns on a regular basis? Really?